# In Sitecore how can I get the date and time that an item entered a workflow state?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

Given a particular item and a particular workflow state, how can I get the date and time that it entered that workflow state in code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should take a look at `GetHistory` method of `Sitecore.Workflows.HistoryStore` class. It's an abstract class, and its only implementation in clean Sitecore is `Sitecore.Data.SqlServer.SqlServerHistoryStore`.

The `GetHistory` method accepts the item, and returns a list of `WorkflowEvent` elements. Each element contains old state, new state, user who did the action, the user's comment and **the date**. Obviously, that's the date when the state was changed.

Sorry, don't have a sample for you right now, but I hope this hint is helpful.

Comment: Thanks.  That seems to sort of work.  I wrote some code that goes through and displays the old state and the new state for everything that is currently in a selected state. For some reason about half of the content items do not show a history entry for the move to their current state.  Do you know why this could happen?  Are there certain situations where a history entry is not recorded?

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea why this could happen... :( You can probably start an new question pasting your sample code - maybe, someone knows the reason...